# how to get some value from php if it is hosted online

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose my php file is and it is hosted online how to get the value of stored in `$mysql`?

```
<?php
    $mysql= new mysqli("localhost","root","","hello",3306);

    if ($mysql->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $mysql->connect_error);
    }
?>
```

Comment: For what purpose do you need value of `$mysql`?

Comment: so that i can ensure no one can get value.. so can you say if that available...

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. What is it - no one can get value?

Comment: Are you worried that someone can access that variable from the internet?

Comment: No one can get its value, and its value wouldn't be very useful to them in this case anyways.

Comment: Just try to ask your question In a different way. Write it in your own language and have Google translate it for you. The code you are showing is not telling much. Ask exactly what you need done. Let's say someone browses to your website. What do you want him to see? Is he allowed to copy text from your site?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)